# Clicking on links in Outlook gives an error message

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I click on a link within an email in Outlook 2010, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I can fix this by setting my default browser to IE, which then opens the link fine. If I set my default browser to Chrome (which is what I actually want), I get the above error again.

How can I fix it so that the links open in Chrome?

<sub>Background:</sub>

<sub>I recently had a problem auto-updating chrome, so I had to reinstall it. In doing so, it seems to have changed from being installed in my profile directory (C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome) to being in Program Files. My feeling is that the location of Chrome in the default browsers has not been updated correctly.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This became too annoying and I have fixed it myself after doing a bit of digging - the problem appears to be to do with Chrome, not Outlook.

The registry key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML.adrian\shell\open\command` was still pointing to the location of Chrome within my profile instead of in `Program Files`. Altering this key to have the new path fixed the behaviour when clicking on links in Outlook.